# Cakephp 3 how to order the results by other tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

im using Cakephp 3 and im facing a problems with ordering the results

**Tables**

1. participants
2. occupations
3. events
4. sorting_settings

**Each participant has occupation**

**Each Events has sorting_settings**

**Sorting Settings table has**

id  ------- occupation_id ---------- sort_number ----------- event_id

i want to display all participant ordered by 
Participant.Events(belong to Participant.sorting_settings.**sort_number** asc how i can do that ?

This is my tried

```
 $query = $this->Participants->find('all')->contain(
                ['Events'=>['Sorting_settings'=> ['sort' => ['Sorting_settings.sort_number' => 'asc']]],'Occupations'])
            ->where(
                ['Participants.approved'=>false,
                'Participants.is_sms_sent'=>false,
                'Participants.is_cancel'=>false,
                'Events.id'=>$eventID,
                'gender'=>$gender])
                ->order(['Participants.is_first_time , Sorting_settings.sort_number asc, desc,Participants.created asc '])
                 ->limit($limitEachTime);
                 foreach($query as $participantToSort){

                      //  debug($participantToSort);
                     echo $participantToSort->id." OC => ".$participantToSort->occupation_id."<br />";
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this sorting number is, do you mean order? Have you tried TreeBehaviors you can create a menu. And I would change your term participants to person and then name your list of people for said event participants.

//sudo code
ParticipantsTable

```
id - person_id - parent_id - event_id
```

//Participants Controller

```
 $descendants = $this->Participants
                    ->find('children', ['for' => $head])
                    ->find('threaded')   
                    ->where('event_id' => $id)

                    ->toArray();

    $this->set('participants', $descendants );
```

//in initialized in your ParticipantsTable.php

```
    $this->addBehavior('Tree');

    $this->belongsTo('ParentMenus', [
        'className' => 'Participants',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('ChildMenus', [
        'className' => 'Participants',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    ]);
```

Read all about it in TreeBehaviors

**Response to comment**

I see so when you say sort numbers you are referring to what i call tiers. More than one person can have the same sort number correct?

And the sort number is attached to the occupation?

One trick if your stuck is to start backwards.

```
 Sort Table hasMany Occupants 
 Occupants hasMany Partcipants
 Partcipants hasMany Events
```

//sudo

```
  $this->SortSettings->find('all')->order([sortnumber => 'asc' ] )->where(sort.occupants.particpants.events => $id);
```

Comment: Hello thanks for reply , i mean i would like to order the participants based on the sort number of that event , example if I'm a participant in event id 7 , and my occupation_id in participant table is 5 , and my occupation_id sort number in Sorting_Settings table is 3 , and other participant have same event_id 7 and his occupation_id sort number in Sorting_Settings table is 2

i want to display all participants ordered by sort_number  acs so in this example i should get the second participant then i'm , wish you got it